# How to determine which button called a function?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I know which button caused this function to run? Specifically, if I want to set the value of the function to be equivalent to the value of the button?

```
var foo_button = document.getElementById("foo_button");
var bar_button = document.getElementById("bar_button");
foo_button.onclick = foo_or_bar;
bar_button.onclick = foo_or_bar;
```

Then in a function later on:

```
function foo_or_bar(){

    //this should return the value of the button that was pressed (in this case "foo" 
    //or "bar"
    return button_that_sent_me;

}
```

Is there a way I can detect the value of which button caused this to occur?

Comment: you mean `this`?

Comment: Would i not need to pass anything? Sorry, new to javascript

Comment: onclick happens in the context of the sender.

Comment: Check the id and return the correct button. `this.id`

Comment: Thank you, in the words of Forest Gump "I am not a smart man"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *this* as @A1rPun says or access the button through window.event, which also helps when you use inline onclicks, and other unrecommended practices:

JS

```
function foo_or_bar() {
  console.log(window.event.target.value);
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="foo_button" value="foo">internals</button>
```

Gives you the following console log:

```
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' sends all information associated with the element fire the event:

```
<button onclick="foo_or_bar(this.id);" id="foo">Foo</button>

function foo_or_bar(id) {
    button_that_sent_me = id;
}
```